# Angular Make HttpClient Get's Wait

Tags: angular, typescript, http, httpclient

So here I will initialise my arrays with the call `this.Reload.All()` to go and get all the arrays I need to filter things later in the program. What happens is that all 4 the calls are made **and then** the 4 responses come back. This confuses & breaks the service because it cannot take in so many calls before giving back their responses. What I am looking for is a synchronous solution that would do something like this: call 1 - response 1 - call 2 - response 2 - call 3 - response 3 - call 4 - response 4. The reponse.dbX_response.view is just the way my JSON comes back from the server.

All of my code is working correctly, it is just the async that is breaking my calls. How can I fix this?

```
//Reload Reference Arrays
    RefVehicleTypes = [];
    RefClients = [];
    RefUsers = [];
    RefObjects = [];

//Reload Class:
    Reload = {
        DoCall : (pUrl, pArray, pResponse) => {
            this.HttpClient.get(pUrl).subscribe(
                (response: any) => {
                    this[pArray] = eval(pResponse);
                    console.log(pResponse + ' : ' + this[pArray]);
                }
            );   
        },
        All : () => {
            this.Reload.VehicleTypes();
            this.Reload.Clients();
            this.Reload.Users();
            this.Reload.Objects();
        },
        VehicleTypes : () => {
            this.Reload.DoCall(
                'http://...',
                'RefVehicleTypes',
                'response.dbVehicleType_response.view',
            );
        },
        Clients : () => {
            this.Reload.DoCall(
                'http://...',
                'RefClients',
                'response.dbClient_response.view',
            );
        },
        Users : () => {
            this.Reload.DoCall(
                'http://...',
                'RefUsers',
                'response.dbUser_response.view'
            );
        },
        Objects : () => {
            this.Reload.DoCall(
                'http://...',
                'RefObjects',
                'response.dbObject_response.view'
            );
        }
    }
```

**NEW EDIT:**

So I replaced the **DoCall** and **All** methods with this, but this still doesn't work. Check the screenshot below for the results.

```
DoCall : (pUrl, pArray, pResponse) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.HttpClient.get(pUrl).subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                console.log('##############################' + pArray)
                console.log(this[pArray]);
                this[pArray] = eval(pResponse);
                console.log(this[pArray]);
                resolve();
            }
        )
    });
},
All : async () => {
    await this.Reload.VehicleTypes();
    await this.Reload.Clients();
    await this.Reload.Users();
    await this.Reload.Objects();
},
```

Here are 3 screenshots of 3 refreshes. As you can see, it seems like the async **All()** function causes the arrays to be mixed around, which is ok. Not sure why but it is still somehow delaying the responses. The last one always works, which probably means the previous responses are being replaced by the next one coming in?

[image]

Comment: Return a promise in your `DoCall` method and chain the commands in your `All` method or use `await`

Comment: Fussel would you mind writing out a basic example of this? I am quite new to angular and promises are quite tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is only written here, so the code is not tested, but something like this should work to make your calls synchronous.

```
Reload = {
    DoCall : (pUrl, pArray, pResponse) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.HttpClient.get(pUrl).subscribe(
                (response: any) => {
                    this[pArray] = eval(pResponse);
                    console.log(pResponse + ' : ' + this[pArray]);

                    resolve();
                }
            );  
        }
    },
    All : () => {
        this.Reload.VehicleTypes().then(() => {
            return this.Reload.Clients();
        }).then(() => {
            return this.Reload.Users();
        }).then(() => {
            return this.Reload.Objects();
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("Everything reloaded");
        });
    },
    VehicleTypes : () => {
        return this.Reload.DoCall(
            'http://...',
            'RefVehicleTypes',
            'response.dbVehicleType_response.view',
        );
    },
    Clients : () => {
        return this.Reload.DoCall(
            'http://...',
            'RefClients',
            'response.dbClient_response.view',
        );
    },
    Users : () => {
        return this.Reload.DoCall(
            'http://...',
            'RefUsers',
            'response.dbUser_response.view'
        );
    },
    Objects : () => {
        return this.Reload.DoCall(
            'http://...',
            'RefObjects',
            'response.dbObject_response.view'
        );
    }
}
```

Alternatively in newer JS version you could use

```
All : async () => {
    await this.Reload.VehicleTypes();
    await this.Reload.Clients();
    await this.Reload.Users();
    await this.Reload.Objects();
},
```

while still using promises.

Comment: So I tried your solution (thought I added **async** in the **All()** function otherwise the awaits give an error, is this wrong?). This is still not working though. Have a look at my edited question please :)

Comment: Do you also return the promise in your other methods?

Comment: Again I am very new so not sure, don't think so. This is the only place where I now use promises. I have exactly the code in my original question, except for the changed **DoCall** and **All** methods, that now look like the **edit** post

Comment: In my code there is also a `return` in all other methods aswell so that these return the promise to the `All` method where the await is used.

Comment: DUDE THANK YOU THIS WORKS! This is a problem I have been battling with for such a long time. Would you might explaining the "Alternatively in newer JS version you could use" part? If I use await here then the await words give an error? Maybe edit your post?

Comment: I have not really worked with await myself this far, just knew of it and it can make the code a bit cleaner in looks. Maybe I'll just remove it.

Comment: NO DON'T DELETE THAT, PUT IT BACK! It is a good answer...you should just change the line `All : () => {` to `All : async () => {`. This seems to work. Like in my post

Comment: xD Ok, its back in.

Comment: Cool man! Thank you once again, I have battled with this problem for a few months now, was using a workaround but I felt it was time to find a legit solution haha.